# multi processing issue in python

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

For some reason, I can not do parallel processing by python. Fo example by running the below code, I get runtime errors:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import time
def sleep_for_a_bit(seconds):
    print(f'Sleeping {seconds} second(s)')
    time.sleep(seconds)
    print("Done Sleeping")
p1=mp.Process(target=sleep_for_a_bit,args=[1])
p2=mp.Process(target=sleep_for_a_bit,args=[1])

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    mp.freeze_support()
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
finish=time.perf_counter()
print("finish running after seconds : ",finish)
```

**this is the error message:**

```
    RuntimeError: 
    An attempt has been made to start a new process before the
    current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.
    This probably means that you are not using fork to start your
    child processes and you have forgotten to use the proper idiom
    in the main module:
    if __name__ == '__main__': 

    freeze_support()
        ...
    The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program
    is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.`
```

Comment: You need to call `p1.join()` and `p2.join()` so that the children processes finish before the parent one. Furthermore it is probably better to put the creation of the processes in the main too. Note that I cannot reproduce your problem on my machine (on Linux)

Comment: please look at "https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.get_context" I copy-pasted the first example after "shared memory" part:    
         from multiprocessing import Process, Value, Array

def f(n, a):
    n.value = 3.1415927
    for i in range(len(a)):
        a[i] = -a[i]

if _ _name_ _ == '_ _main_ _':
    num = Value('d', 0.0)
    arr = Array('i', range(10))

    p = Process(target=f, args=(num, arr))
    p.start()
    p.join()

    print(num.value)
    print(arr[:])    it doesn't work neither

Comment: I dot not see any valid code from the doc where processes are created outside the main. In fact the doc said not to do that: "Instead one should protect the “entry point” of the program by using `if __name__ == '__main__'`". For the `join`, I agree. The only case where it is allowed seems to be with `freeze_support` which only target Windows machine. I guess you have a Windows OS, isn't it? It seems the multiprocessing support on Windows is a bit strange...

Comment: I have both windows machine and mac, for both, I could not run the code provided by the official python documentation website. Do you have a small sample code that I can try?

Answer (score 0):

I have a Windows desktop and it actually ran (maybe I was lucky). But in general, on platforms such as Windows that use `spawn` to create new platforms, you should take all code that you do not want your newly created processes to execute out of global scope since these processes will be created by launching a new Python interpreter and restarting executing from the top of the program and if the code is not contained within a `if __name__ == '__main__':` block, it will be executed. So my best suggestion is to try the following (I have made a few corrections to the code):

```py
import multiprocessing as mp
import time
def sleep_for_a_bit(seconds):
    print(f'Sleeping {seconds} second(s)')
    time.sleep(seconds)
    print("Done Sleeping")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    mp.freeze_support() # not required unless you are creating an .exe file
    p1=mp.Process(target=sleep_for_a_bit,args=[1])
    p2=mp.Process(target=sleep_for_a_bit,args=[1])
    start = time.perf_counter()
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p1.join() # wait for process to finish
    p2.join() # wait for process to finish
    finish=time.perf_counter()
    # perf_counter() is only meaningful when you take the difference between readings:
    print("finish running after seconds : ", finish - start)
```

Prints:

```
Sleeping 1 second(s)
Sleeping 1 second(s)
Done Sleeping
Done Sleeping
finish running after seconds :  1.0933153999999998
```